# Set URL params while testing with Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

My component has:

```
 class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm:
        typeof this.props.match.params.searchTerm !== "undefined"
          ? this.props.match.params.searchTerm
          : ""
    };
  }
```

and the test is:

```
 test("Search should render correct amount of shows", () => {
  const component = shallow(<Search shows={preload.shows} />);
  expect(component.find(ShowCard).length).toEqual(preload.shows.length);
});
```

I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

How can I fix that or how to set query params in my test?

Comment: This error means that `this.props.match` doesn't exist. Does your search component work when running normally?

Comment: yes,it works ok

Comment: fixed that by adding defaultProps. Is that good approach?

Comment: i mean my component will work ok even without defaultProps.The question is whether it's ok to add something to code just for my tests.

Comment: Including `defaultProps` and `propTypes` is a sensible idea in react anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like when outside the test, the `Search` component receives the `match` props correctly.
You could pass it as props when shallow rendering it in the test:

```js
test("Search should render correct amount of shows", () => {
 const match = { params: { searchTerm: 'foo' } }
 const component = shallow(<Search shows={preload.shows} match={match}/>);
 expect(component.find(ShowCard).length).toEqual(preload.shows.length);
});
```

And in that case, you're not changing the component under test in a bad way, your test case just found a bug, which is good and should be aimed in tests, and you improved the component by implementing a default props, making it more robust.

Comment: what if you are using URLSearchParams, how do you mock that in the test

Comment: That is a web API, thus, it's not available in the node environment of Jest,  you need to create your own mock implementation or install a node implementation, but the main point is that you need to set the URLSearchParams name globally in some test setup file or use dependency injection in the module you use it, passing the mock or node implementation as dependency when testing the module.

Answer (score 7):

you should defined a location first in your it/test.

```js
it('App init', async () => {
  const location = {
    ...window.location,
    search: '?scope=3&elementId=25924',
  };
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: location,
  })

  ……
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

I also faced same issue and solved by adding a match prop in the component when you pass it in shallow or mount method. Here is the code:

```
     test("Add param in component", () => {
        const match = {params : { id: 1 } };
        const component = shallow(<YourComponent match={match} />);
        expect(/*Write your code here */);
     });
```

As you can see I and having a param as id, replace with whatever is your's.

Comment: You shouldn't really set code in your app to deal with test implementations, better to mock the output in your test.