# Test url params in react-testing-library without react-router

Tags: reactjs, url, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a widget that uses React but not the `react-router` package. One component checks for the existence of a url param via the `URLSearchParams` API and then opens or closes using styling:

```js
function App() {
  const openWidget =
    new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
      .get("openWidget")
      ?.toLowerCase() === "true";

  const [show, setShow] = useState(openWidget);

  return (<StyledComponent $show={show}>something</StyledComponent>) // set height to 0 or 100vh based on $show
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to test this in rtl. My current test is like so:

```js
    const location = {
      ...window.location,
      search: "openWidget=true",
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
      value: location,
    });
    customRender(<ChatWindow />, { contextProps: amendedMockContext });
    const chatWindow = screen.getByTestId("chat-window");
    expect(chatWindow).toHaveStyle("max-height: 100vh");
```

But when I log out `window.location`, I get this: `{ search: '' }`. My test throws this error:

```sh
    - Expected

    - max-height: 100vh;
    + max-height: 0px;
```

What's the right way to test values using search params?

Note: I have other tests using the same `customRender` and `amendedMockContext` - it has nothing to do with them.

EDIT: I tried making a minimal reproducible example, and it works just fine: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-url-params-hvwkbf?file=/src/App.test.js) . But in my actual project it still doesn't work. The code sandbox is set up identically (context, styles, `customerRender`, everything) yet that one works, and in my own project `window.location.search` still returns an empty string. I am utterly dumbfounded.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. The unit test works as expected on [this repo](https://github.com/fappaz/so-71198186) I just created. Alternatively, have you tried  adding [`writable: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962214/2516673) to your `Object.defineProperty`? I'm afraid we won't be able to help any further unless your share your repository or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Fappaz I tried making a minimal reproducible example, and it works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-url-params-hvwkbf?file=/src/App.test.js . But in my actual project it still doesn't work. The code sandbox is set up identically (context, styles, customerRender, everything) yet that one works, and in my own project `window.location.search` still returns an empty string. I am utterly dumbfounded.

Comment: That sounds like a configuration issue in your dev environment. You could try a different node version, or make sure your dependencies have the same version as the ones in your codesandbox.

Comment: @Fappaz Node versions are the same - as ensured by the `sandbox.config.json` that I just added. Package versions were a couple of build steps down, but that's all. Updated them and still doesn't work. A real mystery, but the important thing is that url param testing evidently does work with the object.defineProperty method.

Answer (score 0):

The last comment in this issue on GitHub Jest repository will help you

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124#issuecomment-914606939

Using `history.replaceState` should allow you to change URL `search` parameter.

Check the other replies in the issue I shared, seems that most of the techniques that were working before to change `window.location` are not working anymore in the last versions of Jest.

**Example**

Following your comment about the URL parameter, the point to note here is that, for this test in particular, the only thing that is important for you is the query string, so you can use any valid origin as parameter and eventually, if in another test you need a specific origin, you can pass it to the function. Let me show you an example, created starting from the link I shared.

```
function changeJSDOMURL(search, url = "https://www.example.com/") {
  const newURL = new URL(url);
  newURL.search = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const href = `${window.origin}${newURL.pathname}${newURL.search}${newURL.hash}`;
  history.replaceState(history.state, null, href);
}

// This will consider the default URL, it is OK for your test
changeJSDOMURL({ openWidget: "true" });

// If you need to pass an origin different from the default one
changeJSDOMURL({ openWidget: "true" }, "https://www.something.io");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, would you mind providing a little more context? I have implemented the `changeJSDOMURL` function, but the only thing I know to pass in as `url` is `?openWidget=true`, which throws an error as being an invalid URL. Do I need to supply a full path? If so I don't know what that path should be. surely not `https://localhost:3000`?

Comment: @crevulus, check the edits, basically the URL is not relevant for your test since you are working on the search instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but this still didn't work. It still didn't change the value of `window.location.search` -- it was still an empty string. I've added an edit with some updates. I'm so incredibly confused by why this is happening.

Comment: @crevulus, at this point I think you are changing the URL after your expression have been evaluated. Check when the value of your parameter is used and when you are changing the state.